# Is there an easy way to convert LFs to CRLFs on a Chromebook?

Tags: newlines

The subject line says it all: is there an easy way -- something equivalent to the linux "unix2dos" utility, or a very old Macintosh droplet that I have on my home iMac -- to convert a text file from *nix-style line termination to DOS-style line termination?

Answer (score 0):

If Google's [Set up Linux on your Chromebook](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9145439) does what I think it does, you can install and use Linux tools such as `unix2dos` or just use something like `sed` or `awk` to do [the same thing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/153091/2974)

> Linux is off by default. You can turn it on any time from Settings.
>
> 1. On your Chromebook, at the bottom right, select the time.
> 2. Select Settings  and then **Advanced** and then **Developers.**
> 3. Next to "Linux development environment," select **Turn On**.
> 4. Follow the on-screen instructions. Setup can take 10 minutes or more.
> 5. A terminal window opens. You have a Debian 10 (Buster) environment. You can run Linux commands, install more tools using the
>    APT package manager, and customize your shell.

So you should be able to use something like `apt install unix2dos` or `sudo apt-get install unix2dos` or one of the variations on that idea.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I'm already using Firefox, Thunderbird, LibreOffice, and GnuBackgammon in the linux subsystem, and I have little doubt that I could use the package containing unix2dos, but I'd probably be stuck with doing it from a Linux command line. I was hoping for something more convenient to use.
Then again, on the DOS side of the equation, I've already written a utility that converts UTF-8 to something Xerox Ventura Publisher understands, and it wouldn't be all that difficult to do the *nix-to-DOS conversion on that end as well.

Comment: also.. `dos2unix`.. it's partner in crime.